# How do I correctly write this django model relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-admin

```
class A:
   a = models.CharField()

class B:
   aa = models.ForeignKey(A) # refering A.a
   b = models.CharField()


class C:
   c = models.CharField()
   aa = models.ForeignKey(B) # refering B.aa
   bb = models.ForeignKey(B) # refering B.b
```

To make things simple, let us say A contains three entries: u, v and w 
and B contains: (u, x), (u, y), (u,z), (v,x), (v, k) and (w,y).

Now I want the admin to be able to be able to create instances of C where first he enters value for field c and the select any one of (u, v, w) for field aa.

After selecting u ->  x, y, z should appear for selection for bb,

After selecting v ->  x and k should appear for selection for bb,

After selecting w -> only x should appear for selection for bb,

Unfortunately, after many tries I am not able to correctly write the Foreign key relationship that does exactly what I intend to do.

**Edit:**

```
 # myapp/models.py
 from django.db import models
 from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey


class Continent(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Location(models.Model):
newcontinent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
newcountry = ChainedForeignKey(
    Country, # the model where you're populating your countries from
    chained_field="newcontinent", # the field on your own model that this field links to
    chained_model_field="continent", # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
   # show_all=False, # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
)

my_address = models.CharField(max_length=20)


#myapp/forms.py
from myapp.models import Location
from django.forms import ModelForm

class LocationForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ['newcontinent', 'newcountry', 'my_address']


#myapp/templates/myapp/addLocationForm.html   
{% extends 'registration/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add a new location{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit"> Post </button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}

#myapp/views.py
def addlocation(request):
if request.POST == "POST":
    form = LocationForm()
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('home')
else:
    form = LocationForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/addLocationForm.html', { 'form': form})


#urls.py
 url(r'^location/add/$', core_views.addlocation,name='add-location'),
```

The above code does not work. I am able to select Continent added by admin. However, no option for selection of country appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is bit unclear, but I think what you want can be achieved using **django-smart-selects** and its **chained foreign key**.

[Just have a look here](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) go through it and then try it on your project.

I am quite sure it will work for you.

Comment: It did work properly for admin. The admin is able to do everything that I desired. However, making a ModelForm, or a CreateView for the same model doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: I have edited the question with all my code. Can you spot the error?

Answer (score 0):

If smart select works in the admin page then include in your html file the following and it will work. The order is important.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js</script>
    <script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedm2m.js' %}"></script>
```